# Get virtual path for a full path in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, server.mappath, virtual-path

How can I get the virtual path for a full path in ASP classic.  Note that the full path may be under a virtual directory and therefore the simplistic

```
virtPath = Replace(fullPath, Server.MapPath("/"), "")
```

method will not work.

Edit: To clarify, an example follows

- Full Windows File Path (known):
  **\\MyServer\MyShare\Web\Site\Logs\Test.txt**
- My Website has a Virtual directory
  called **Logs** that Points to **\\MyServer\MyShare\Web\Site\Logs\**.
- Virtual Path (unknown): **/Logs/Text.txt**
- Http path (unknown, needed):
  **http://Site/Logs/Test.txt**
- The code is in a asp page in the main app, not under any virtual directories.  It is located on a separate server from the file in question.
- IIS 6.0

  How do I find the virtual path from the full file path?

Comment: Can you clarify one more thing, where is this code running?  In an ASP page in your app?

Comment: Also what IIS version?  IIS6?

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone's interested, Anthony Jones' answer showed me the way to getting the application's relative root consistently. So if you have a site at http://example.com and a local development equivalent at http://localhost/example, you can find your root with this function:

```
Function ToRootedVirtual(relativePath)
    Dim applicationMetaPath : applicationMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH")
    Dim instanceMetaPath : instanceMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH")
    Dim rootPath : rootPath = Mid(applicationMetaPath, Len(instanceMetaPath) + Len("/ROOT/"))
    ToRootedVirtual = rootPath + relativePath
End Function
```

You can then call it like this to get the root path:

```
ToRootedVirtual("/")
```

Which will return:

- / on example.com
- /example/ on localhost/example

You can also use it without the slash:

```
ToRootedVirtual("")
```

Comment: I really don't like classic asp due to these little quirks, which most modern web languages have addressed, but people still want Classic ASP sites... oh the humanity. But this worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: Though of course that approach doesn't work in in global.asa where you have no access to the Request object.

Comment: This is one great solution to similar problem of mine!

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood the question.

**Assumption**

The full path is a path with in the current application or a child application.  It is not a path limited to the parent nor a path into a sibling application.  The desired path is relative to the current applications path.

**Scenario 1**

A path such as

"/someApp/someFolder/someSubFolder/file.ext"

should resolve it to:-

"~/someFolder/someSubFolder/file.ext"

(although the ~/ notation isn't something ASP classic understands).

**Scenario 2**

"/someApp/someSubApp/SomeSubFolder/file.ext"

you still want:-

"~/someFolder/someSubFolder/file.ext"

**Scenario 3**

The app is the root application of the site:-

"/someFolder/someSubFolder/file.ext"

would still become

"~/someFolder/someSubFolder.file.ext"

**Solution**

The key to solving this is:-

```
Dim sAppMetaPath : sAppMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH")
```

For the above set of scenarios this will result in something like:-

1. "/LM/W3SVC/33230916/Root/someApp"
2. "/LM/W3SVC/33230916/Root/someApp/someSubApp"
3. "/LM/W3SVC/33230916/Root"

Also

```
Dim sInstanceMetaPath: sInstanceMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH")
```

will in all the scenarios return

"/LM/W3SVC/33230916"

With some mathematical reduction we can arrive at the function:-

```
Function ToAppRelative(virtualPath)

    Dim sAppMetaPath : sAppMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH")
    Dim sInstanceMetaPath: sInstanceMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH")

    ToAppRelative = "~/" & Mid(virtualPath, Len(sAppMetaPath) - Len(sInstanceMetaPath) - 3)

End Function
```

Comment: Not quite right unfortunately, see the edit for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Although there may be a better way, I always did this by creating a config variable where I manually specify the root path that is not part of the virtual path. This is because you do not know if the site will be deployed as root, under a folder in root web, or in a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

well, my answer isn't better than OrbMan's...

I have organized my app in such a way that every include is relative...

that is

instead of \myapp\lib\somefile.asp I use ..\lib\somefile.asp

in other cases I just do what Orbman said...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you solve root-relatie pathing in html via ASP so your site can be portable to different hosting directories.

This little snippet will produce the correct prefix to set your URLs:

```
Mid(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH"),Len(Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH"))+6)
```

You can use this in LINKs, IMGs, hyperlinks, etc as follows:

```
<link href="<%= Mid(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH"),Len(Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH"))+6) %>/assets/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

so, code your paths to be root-relative (starts with a /) and then put this snippet right in front of that first slash, inside the quotes:

Answer (score 0):

**The server's virtual path is:**

```
<%Response.Write "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("server_name") &  
left(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"),InStrRev(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"),"/"))   %>
</p>
```