# Is there an easier way to do Classic ASP "relative path"?

Tags: asp-classic

Right now, I'm having trouble.
First of all I have a page, let's call it "http://blah.com/login".

That obviously goes strait to "index.asp"

A line of Main.asp:

```
<!--#include file="resource/menu.asp"-->
```

Page top includes all of what I need for my menu... so:

Part of resource/menu.htm:

```
<div id="colortab" class="ddcolortabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="main.asp" title="Main" rel="dropmain"><span>Main</span></a></li>
```

...

```
</ul>
</div>
<!--Main drop down menu -->
<div id="dropmain" class="dropmenudiv_a">
<a href="main/announcements.asp">Announcements</a>
<a href="main/contacts.asp">Contact Information</a>
<a href="main/MeetingPlans.asp">Meeting Plan</a>
<a href="main/photos.asp">Photo Gallery</a>
<a href="main/events.asp">Upcoming Events</a>
</div>
```

Let's say I click on the "announcements" (http://blah.com/login/main/announcements.asp) link... Now I'm at the announcements page!
But wait, I include the same menu file. Guess what happens:
I get sent to "http://blah.com/login/main/main/announcements.asp
Which doesn't exist...

My solution:
Make a menu_sub.asp include for any subpages.
But wait a second... this WORKS, but it gets REALLY REALLY messy... What can I do to use just one main "menu.asp" instead of "menu_sub.asp"? using "/main/announcements.asp" WON'T be an option because this is a web application that will be on different directories per server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic bullet fix. Here is how I would do this.

1. Create a separate include file that DIM's and Initializes global variables called info.asp
2. Inside info.asp DIM a variable called strRelativePath and initialize it to ""
3. Include info.asp at the top of each asp page above the menu.asp include
4. Modify menu.asp and include <%=strRelativePath%> in all the urls
5. Inside each asp page set strRelativePath as necessary:

```
<!--#include file="includes/info.asp"-->
strRelativePath = "Login/"
<!--#include file="resource/menu.asp"-->
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this function to your menu.asp:

```
    Function GetApplicationPath()
        GetApplicationPath = Mid(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH"), Len(Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH")) + 6) & "/"
    End Function

    Dim prefix: prefix = GetApplicationPath()
```

Now structure your references in the menu.asp using:

```
<a href="<%=prefix%>main/announcements.asp">Announcements</a>
```

This will make these references absolute but they will vary appropriately with whatever virtual folder path the website has your ASP application installed under.

Comment: I do not have time to try this now, but this looks like it is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Comment: I just tested it. prefix gets set to "/" however I need it to get set to "/login/"...

Comment: Alex: "login" is your folder right?  You know where it is relative your application's root folder.  What I understood your problem to be is that your application may be placed in a larger website in a folder that is unknown to you at development time.  The helper function I've provided gives you the virtual path from the the current website's root to the your applications root folder.  This allows you to build absolute paths dynamically that correct for the specific website.  A path of "/" means that your root folder has not been configured as an application.

Comment: [Click here to download my source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50750605/WebDesign/Scouting%20Network.zip)

However, global.asa is in the root of my ftp, but the rest is is /login

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888147/get-virtual-path-for-a-full-path-in-asp-classic) where the highest rated answer states that you can find the root with the following function:

```
Function ToRootedVirtual(relativePath)
    Dim applicationMetaPath : applicationMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH")
    Dim instanceMetaPath : instanceMetaPath = Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH")
    Dim rootPath : rootPath = Mid(applicationMetaPath, Len(instanceMetaPath) + Len("/ROOT/"))
    ToRootedVirtual = rootPath + relativePath
End Function
```

You can then call it:

```
ToRootedVirtual("/")
```

or

```
ToRootedVirtual("/index.asp")
```

etc. to return the root from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Virtual` instead of `File` because `Virtual` accepts an absolute path from the root directory, not relative like `File`.

Like this:

```
  <!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/resource/menu.asp"-->
```

Also, make sure your IIS settings allow Includes, See this link for details: 
http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/server-side-includes-for-html-in-iis7

Comment: As I said before, I am unable to do that because this application can sometimes be entirely uploaded under a directory, or sometimes on the root. Right now it's on the login directory off the root, so if I wanted to I could type:
    <!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/login/resource/menu.asp"-->
But it needs to be versitile for whereever it gets uploaded. I do appreciate the response though!

Answer (score 0):

**This can be fixed with the HTML base tag:**

*Add this tag in the beginning of each page:*

```
<base href="http://blah.com/login">
```